# Infinite series and the IMO

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been stuck at this problem, as my approaches have not led me to the proper result. The problem is as follows:

Prove that if $|x| <1$, then $$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} + \frac{x^3}{(1-x^3)^2}\cdots = \frac{x}{1-x} + \frac{2x^2}{1+x^2} +\frac{3x^3}{1-x^3}\cdots$$

I tried finding the generalised term of the two sequences on either side of the equality but I couldn't go in the right approach. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Simplify the fractions in the second series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $|x|<1$, the LHS is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{(-x)^k}{(1+(-x)^k)^2}
&=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-(-x)^k)^n\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nn\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k((-x)^n)^k\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nn\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-(-x)^n)^k\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{1+(-x)^n}
\end{align*}
which is the RHS. In the first step and in the last step we used the following identities for $|z|<1$:
$$\frac{z}{(1+z)^2}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-z)^n
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-z)^k=\frac{z}{1+z}.$$

Note that the coefficients of this power series is the OEIS sequence [A046897](https://oeis.org/A046897): the $n$ term is the sum of divisors of $n$ that are not divisible by 4.

Comment: @Rohan Any further doubt?

Comment: (+1) I had to go afk for a while and did not notice that your answer is similar to what I was in the process of writing.

Comment: @robjohn You are real sportsman. I appreciate that!

Comment: IMO, the presentation looks better when formatted with the `align` environment, rather than flowing horizontally.

Comment: Very nice! I'd upvote again now that the formatting is much better.

Comment: I hope you don't mind; I continued the formatting.